# How to switch on HINSTANCE without resorting to const_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, switch-statement, c++17

The title already said it.

See real world example see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-findexecutablea

That returns a HINSTANCE - which is a pointer type - which in some cases can assume predefined error values.

Preferably, I would like to switch on a HINSTANCE and do that without resorting to `const_cast` or a c-style cast - how may that be achieved ?

Sample code:

```
bool test_result(const HINSTANCE ptr) {
  switch (ptr) {
  case 2 /*SE_ERR_FNF*/:
    return false;
  default:
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `switch`? Why not `if (hInst == (HINSTANCE)SE_ERR_FNF) { ... }`?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe well, in practice there are more values/cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing myself because that return type doesn't make much sense but for whatever reason the WinAPI actually does return `void*`. In this case the actual return value is the address the `void*` is pointing to. So you can cast it using `reinterpret_cast` and switch on it:

```
bool test_result(const HINSTANCE ptr) {
  switch (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr)) {
  case 2 /*SE_ERR_FNF*/:
    return false;
  default:
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be cast with `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @Bathsheba Now that we're dynamically casting you let's get 2 birds with one stone and find out.

Comment: In the meantime i figured this out as well - duh

Comment: @Bathsheba Chickens are birds right? In that case yes. I still miss old Freddy.

Comment: @Darune I noticed, sorry for answering ^^

Comment: My other comment will self-destruct in 30 seconds. This is why I can't nominate myself as a moderator ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I will nominate you.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Think we're too late this year ;-)

Comment: Don't betray me though and start deleting my very useful comments when you get mod.

Comment: just a note: the top-level `const` on the function parameter here is completely pointless 

Comment: @MichaelKenzel i just copied over the function from OP. Also please get those ugly emoji's out of here.

Comment: @SombreroChicken have you considered intptr_t or uintptr_t as more appropriate here since it is coming from a pointer

Comment: @darune Yeah, that's the correct type to use in this case.

Answer (score 3):

for converting a pointer (HINSTANCE is just a void*) to an int you `reinterpret_cast` to a `uintptr_t`. Like this:

```
bool test_result(const HINSTANCE ptr)
{
  switch (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr))
  {
  case 2 /*SE_ERR_FNF*/:
    return false;
  default:
    return true;
  }
}
```